# No "Set-Cookie" Header in NSURLResponse

Tags: ios, http, header, nsurlrequest, setcookie

When I do a request for http://www.google.com from iOS and 
look over the returned headers by getting them like so:

---

NSDictionary *dictionary = [response allHeaderFields];

---

I don't see "Set-Cookie" in there. While when I am using a different Client, 
I see that header.

I tried changing the User-Agent, but with no effect. I tried changing
the cachepolicy but with no effect...

Comment: when you use a different "client" to make the request, which other client are you using?  Mobile Safari?  Or some other app with a "`UIWebView`" built-in?  It may simply be that you haven't logged in or authenticated or had a reason for a cookie to be set from your own NSURLRequest.